# How to get path of image form Resource of main bundle

Tags: iphone, swift, xcode, ios6

i have an iPhone application in which i added `images` directory (Group) in to `Resources` (group). i want to access that images which is in `images`. I need a path to that images so i create a code like following.

```
NSString *imagePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"myImage1" ofType:@"png" inDirectory:@"images"];
NSLog(@"%@", imagePath);
```

Result :

```
(null)
```

i also tried this code

```
NSString *imagePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"myImage1" ofType:@"png"];
```

But this code gives me `(null)` result.

`myImage1` 's path is `Resources/images/myImage1.png`

I don't know what is the problem. Please suggest some fixes.

Comment: i copied file name from bundle so no worry for case sensitivity.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Adding image by following method solved my problem.

- Right click on project in xcode and select `Add Files to "project name"`.
- Select your image file from computer local disk.
- In the pop-up window make sure you select `Copy items into destination group's folder` and `Create Folder References for any added folders` and `Add to targets`.
- click `Add`.

Then with bellow code i can retrieve my image.

For **Objective-C** version

```
[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"imageName" ofType:@"png"];
```

For **Swift 4.0** version

```
Bundle.main.path(forResource: "imageName", ofType: "png")
```

Answer (score 7):

for soultion....

Go to : Target -> "Build Phases" -> "copy bundle Resources" Then add that particular file here.

clean the project and RUN. It works.

and also see...

[NSBundle pathForResource inDirectory gives nil](http://iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/31256-nsbundle-pathforresource-indirectory-gives-nil.html)

### and also check...

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath];
NSFileManager *fm = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSError *error = [[NSError alloc] init];
NSArray *directoryAndFileNames = [fm contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:path error:&error];
```

print all value of this directoryAndFileNames and check your filename is exist in that or not....

Comment: i get the file list and my `myImage1.png` is there in list. What next ??

Comment: One mistake, don't allocate the error, you should put "error = nil" and pass the address.

Comment: "-[NSError init] called; this results in an invalid NSError instance. It will raise an exception in a future release."
I tried to edit for you, but for some reason exception is not a good enough reason to edit on this site.
I would never understand the logic of the admins here.

Answer (score 0):

Try to check a png file by metadata. May be the file has real format jpg. But not png.

Answer (score -1):

First of all Check if there is a file with name name in the main Bundle.

It gives **null** when there is **no file with such a name**.