# iOS Extension and accessing files in Resource

Tags: ios, file, ios8, nsfilemanager, nsbundle

Suppose I have a file data.txt in the Resource bundle of an extension (not the Resource bundle of the application). How do I access it? I have tried:

```
NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"data" ofType:@"txt"];
```

But it returns nil.

Comment: What do you get inside filePath? Maybe this answer will help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16185287/how-to-get-path-of-image-form-resource-of-main-bundle

Answer (score 1):

It turns out all I need to do is to add this file to the Application's target, and not only the Extension's target.

Answer (score 0):

Add your resource file to main app bundle which contains the extension as embedded binary and then call this method. It will return correct path.